# Android: Firebase DB query for username, create new user record if username does not exist

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Registration form (username, password, phone number) and a submit button. I want to check if this username has been registered before. If it is not then create user with credentials in the form.

DB structure

```
- users
--- -L3HQjgyXe6iNC0r0Ftr
------ mobile: "+15553334444"
------ password: "yoyo"
------ uid: "-L3HQjgyXe6iNC0r0Ftr"
------ username: "myusername"
```

When I check against a username that exists, i get the correct Toast. However, if the username being checked does not exist, it does not run the code in the else statement under the Toast. Any suggestions?

```
btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final String username = txtUsername.getText().toString();
            final String password = txtPassword.getText().toString();
            final String number = txtNumber.getText().toString();
            final boolean[] createUser = new boolean[1];

            user = SerializableHelper.loadDataFromFile(OnBoardingActivity.this);

            if (user != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "User uid: " + user.getUid());
                Log.d(TAG, "User username: " + user.getUsername());
                Toast.makeText(OnBoardingActivity.this, "You're already Registered!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {
                Query query = mFBUsers.orderByChild("username").equalTo(username);
                query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                            if (child.getValue(User.class).getUsername().equals(username)) {
                                Toast.makeText(OnBoardingActivity.this, "username already exists!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            } else {
                                Log.d(TAG, "TELL APP TO CREATE NEW USER");
                                String tempUid = mFBUsers.push().getKey();
                                user = new User(tempUid, username, password, number);

                                // save user data locally before pushing to Firebase
                                SerializableHelper.saveSerializable(OnBoardingActivity.this, user);
                                mFBUsers.child(tempUid).setValue(user);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

One vey obvious problem in your code is that you are updating the `createUser[0]` inside the `onDataChange` method of `ValueEventListener` but you are using it outside it.

Do note that `ValueEventListener` is executed asynchronously. So it will proceed with execution of the remaining code without waiting for `onDataChange` to be called.

So if you want to wait for the updated value of `createUser[0]`, you should call the entire `if` block of code from inside the `onDataChange`

Hope this helps. Let me know if you want me to elaborate further.

Comment: You see, I had the correct logic in the right place as you suggested, inside the onDataChange code block prior to submitting this request. For some odd reason, **it just does not get executed**... I updated the code in my question to reflect the code in the correct place.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured out what my problem code was

```
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                            if (child.getValue(User.class).getUsername().equals(username)) {
                                Toast.makeText(OnBoardingActivity.this, "username already exists!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                return;
                            }
                        }

                        Log.d(TAG, "TELL APP TO CREATE NEW USER");
                        String tempUid = mFBUsers.push().getKey();
                        user = new User(tempUid, username, password, number);

                        // save user data locally before pushing to Firebase
                        SerializableHelper.saveDataToFile(OnBoardingActivity.this, user);
                        mFBUsers.child(tempUid).setValue(user);
                    }
```